# I have a controller that has a get;set that I need to set for testing -- how can I make this test Class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

For more context, there are Programs that make different orders, and the VF Page allows you to choose a program and mass create orders or all eligible accounts or contacts.

The beginning part of the controller shows what's being set from the VF Page...

```
public Order linkedOrder{get;set;} //Placeholder for user input on the VF page
public List<Order> orderList;
public List<Programs_Account_Contact_JO__c> PACJOList;
```

Then in the VF page, there is an option for the Program....

```
            <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" columns="2" id="OrderBlock">
            <apex:inputField value="{!linkedOrder.Program__c}"/>
            <apex:outputText ></apex:outputText>
            <apex:inputField value="{!linkedOrder.EffectiveDate}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!linkedOrder.EndDate}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

What I did in my test class, is I made instances of the various programs able to be used for mass order creation, and I linked them to their accounts (with that Programs_Account_Contact_JO__c object...) and I did the same for another account. I gave one an activated contract, and the other a draft. This Mass Order Creation should only do it for active contracts.

I'm just not sure how to use the test class with this class...that uses VF input.

Comment: To replicate the VF input, you can create an instance of object and assign value to the attribute, like obj.attributeName = 'value';

Comment: I need a lot more context to understand this answer. What is obj, in this case? Where does the setting of the Program get involved in this sort of solution, and how do I make sure my call of this class uses that value?

Comment: Natalie, it's impossible that @SantanuBoral, or I, can answer this properly without seeing your current test code and a description of where it's failing.

Comment: Also you would never need a `public set` on an `sObject`.

Comment: It's not failing, it's just not calling the Class because I don't know, in effect, how. I can post the whole thing but all my test class does is create an account and the programs attached to it. it would be a bit of a clutter to post, but I can if that is necessary.

Comment: It is necessary, IMHO.

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis You might find [Testing Custom Controllers and Controller Extensions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm) a useful starting point. Note the setting of the parameters on the controller, which would work equally well for properties.